# Enable htpps for a website hosted in windows server

Tags: https

Having the SSL certificate supposedly implemented on the server, what's the next step to have "https//" at the beginning of the URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the overwhelming help. I managed to resolve my problem and was actually very simple. I had to create a web.config file and copy paste the next code

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
     <rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.es/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And after that, replace the url with the one from your own web. Simple but if you don´t have any knoledge on the matter is actually very frustrating